# How to connect bluetooth devices using flutter blue plus?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot

I have been using flutter blue plus to connect with ble device, but is there any way you can configure the connection based on UUID of the ble device. I mean, is there any way to use flutter blue plus to connect with ble device using UUID of the device?

Comment: Check out [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) package.